# Correctly displaying structural data in different map projections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, symbology, mapping, geology

How can I ensure the correct display of oriented structural data in GIS at northern latitudes when the map is reprojected.
We are making new geological maps in northern latitudes and have a lot of structural data that we want to display. we can of course display them correctly with the rotation of a symbol by an attribute (strike) in ArcGIS Pro\ArcMap.
However, as our maps make up part of a series which cover more than one UTM zone we must ensure that the symbols are rotated correctly with respect to north as the map is reprojected.
We currently get over this issue by using lines oriented for strike instead of symbols, as the line will reproject but a symbols attribute will not be recalculated so therefore does not rotate.
Is there a way to do this using just the symbols instead of creating line features instead? The structural data must be queriable by the end user and be able to retrieve the strike\dip data, which is easier to do with point data rather than lines...